# Jquery function not changing textbox values

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have written a jQuery function to change text of textboxes to null and passed it to `onClick` event of a button.

```js
$(function ResetForm() {
  $('#TxtFName').val("");
  $('#TxtLName').val("");
  $('#TxtSalary').val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form action="/Employee/SaveEmployee" method="post">
    First Name: <input type="text" id="TxtFName" name="FirstName" value="" /> <br/> Last Name: <input type="text" id="TxtLName" name="LastName" value="" /> <br /> Salary: <input type="text" id="TxtSalary" name="Salary" value="" /> <br />
```

the text values of first name last name and salary not changing. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass this behavior to button click event, try to wire this with button click event implicitly.

```
$( "#targetButton" ).click(function() {
    $('#TxtFName').val("");
    $('#TxtLName').val("");
    $('#TxtSalary').val("");
 });
```

Comment: but why cant i do it with a function call in onclick event?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need that function and dont put `value=""` in each input field because if you will receive that values in other file it would be always empty by default.

```js
$('#reset').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('form').find("#TxtFName, #TxtLName, #TxtSalary").val("");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <form action="/Employee/SaveEmployee" method="post" id="form1">
        First Name: <input type="text" id="TxtFName" name="FirstName"/> <br/>
        Last Name: <input type="text" id="TxtLName" name="LastName" /> <br />
        Salary: <input type="text" id="TxtSalary" name="Salary" /> <br />
        <button type="button" id="reset">Reset</button>
        </form> </div>
```

Comment: I got your answer. but i was trying to convert this javascript to jquery                   <script>
function ResetForm() {
document.getElementById('TxtFName').value = "";
document.getElementById('TxtLName').value = "";
document.getElementById('TxtSalary').value = "";
}
</script>

Comment: thank you. So the way i coded is wrong?  i should always invoke an event when writing functions in jquery? How can i do it with onclick event?

Comment: Yes, it was wrong, u were calling a function whiout a click function.

Comment: cant i use it with <input type buttons ?

Comment: What do u mean?

Comment: <input type="button" name="BtnReset" value="Reset" onclick="ResetForm();"/>  This was the code i as trying to add onclick function. if i add an id to this will it work?

Comment: You need to trigger click if u want to use jquery, I hope it helps u, can you check this answer as accepted please

Answer (score 0):

you can create one function that fire after form submit

```
       $('form').trigger('reset');
```

in function put above code

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

function myFunction()
{
        $("#TxtFName").val("");
        $('#TxtLName').val("");
        $('#TxtSalary').val("");
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<form>
  First Name: <input type="text" id="TxtFName" name="FirstName" value="" /> <br/>
  Last Name: <input type="text" id="TxtLName" name="LastName" value="" /> <br />
  Salary: <input type="text" id="TxtSalary" name="Salary" value="" /> <br />
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Reset</button>
<form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ya.. also i got alternative answers too! :))

Answer (score 0):

You can use this button trigger

```
<form action="/Employee/SaveEmployee" method="post" id="form1">
            First Name: <input type="text" id="TxtFName" name="FirstName"/> <br/>
            Last Name: <input type="text" id="TxtLName" name="LastName" /> <br />
            Salary: <input type="text" id="TxtSalary" name="Salary" /> <br />
            <button type="button" id="reset">Reset</button>
            </form> </div>

$('#reset').click(function(){
 $('#form1').trigger('reset');
  });
```